# Delete the duplicate old records from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have below query which is working as expected. And return a row that I need to delete.

```
SELECT * FROM tests WHERE e2e_product_id=407 AND test_name='PWBAR-FullBalance-Auth-TC1' AND
 test_id<>(SELECT MAX(test_id)AS testid FROM tests WHERE test_name IN 
 (SELECT test_name FROM tests WHERE e2e_product_id=407 GROUP BY test_name HAVING COUNT(*) >1) AND e2e_product_id=407 GROUP BY test_name)
```

I just changed the above query as delete syntax but it return exception

```
Delete FROM tests WHERE e2e_product_id=407 AND test_name='PWBAR-FullBalance-Auth-TC1' AND
 test_id<>(SELECT MAX(test_id)AS testid FROM tests WHERE test_name IN 
 (SELECT test_name FROM tests WHERE e2e_product_id=407 GROUP BY test_name HAVING COUNT(*) >1) AND e2e_product_id=407 GROUP BY test_name)
```

Error:

> Error Code: 1093 You can't specify target table 'tests' for update in
>   FROM clause

How can I delete the data by using above approach. Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this -

```
Delete FROM tests
 WHERE e2e_product_id = 407
   AND test_name = 'PWBAR-FullBalance-Auth-TC1'
   AND test_id <> (SELECT MAX_TEST_ID
                     FROM (SELECT test_name, MAX(test_id) MAX_TEST_ID
                             FROM tests
                            WHERE e2e_product_id = 407
                            GROUP BY test_name
                           HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) TEMP)
```

Comment: Does it work if i have n number of duplicate records? it should n't delete the last record and have to delete the older duplicate records in table.

Comment: I tried its working with two duplicate records. need to check with n number of duplicate reocrds.

Comment: It should work with `n` numbers of duplicates too. Glad to help! :-)

Comment: No. I tried to delete multiple record but query throws below exception    Error Code: 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Pls help me on this.

Comment: can you share the SQL for multiple records?

Answer (score 0):

change YOUR_KEY to your key

```
DELETE FROM TESTS WHERE YOUR_KEY IN(

    SELECT YOUR_KEY FROM tests WHERE e2e_product_id=407 AND test_name='PWBAR-FullBalance-Auth-TC1' AND
     test_id<>(SELECT MAX(test_id)AS testid FROM tests WHERE test_name IN 
     (SELECT test_name FROM tests WHERE e2e_product_id=407 GROUP BY test_name HAVING COUNT(*) >1) AND e2e_product_id=407 GROUP BY test_name)

)
```

Comment: pls explain me what you mentioned about your key. I didn't get